# Set SKU automaticaly in multi vendor website

Tags: magento-1.9, product, sku

I extended my Magento website with a multi vendor module.  Vendors are having problems assigning SKU numbers while creating new products because it often happens that the choosed SKU has already be used by an other vendor.
Is there a way to assign SKU# automatically without vendors having to do it manually? For example assigning as SKU# the same ID# of the product?

Comment: I guess you could try and override the _beforeSave() function of the Product model, and test if the product hasn't been persisted yet then assign it a hand-made sku.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what Julian said is one way, then you can hide sku in the backend form and it still got saved.

The better (but similar way) is to:

1. Create an observer, listen on `catalog_product_save_before`, set the sku to something (this might not be needed, if DB accepts an empty sku
2. Create an observer, listen on `catalog_product_save_after` (before you don't have the ID yet)
3. set the sku = id
4. set some attribute on the product like `setAlreadyObservered(true)`
5. save again
6. make sure to test the attribute in both or your observers to not fall into a saving loop.